# Learning Python & Problem With Basic Functions

Tags: python, list, function

I'm in the process of learning python after been stuck with VBA for about 10 years and decided I ought to learn something more modern. I'm using an on-line course and am at the functions section, which was going okay but during an exercise was asked to create a script that replicates that game where there are 3 cups and 1 ball (nothing to do with 2 girls 1 cup!) and the player has to guess where the ball is.

The object was to replicate this using functions that pass and return arguments between each other. I created what I thought would work...it doesn't but I can't for the life of me figure out why not, and why it's doing certain things. I have spent about 2 hours trying to work it out and got nowhere! I'm currently using Jupyter Notebooks, if that makes any difference.

Bear with me as I haven't posted on here for ages but will try to get the code into a readable format...

```
#example of a function that returns a shuffled list

from random import shuffle   #import the shuffle function from the random library

#create function that will shuffle and input list and return the shuffled list
def shuffle_list(shuffled_list):
    shuffle(shuffled_list)   #randomly shuffles list
    return shuffled_list     #returns the now shuffled list as shuffled_list
```

```
#use a function to get player's guess
def player_guess():    # note functions don't have to accept any input, they can just be called
    
    guess = ""   #create empty string
    
    while guess not in ["0", "1", "2"]:   #keep looping until user inputs one of the allowable numbers
        guess = input ("Pick a number: 0, 1 or 2")
    
    return int(guess)   #need to transform to integer as Input function creates strings
```

```
#we need another function now that takes the results of the shuffled list and compares it to the player's guess

def check_guess(ball_position,guess):   #create function that takes 2 inputs: ball_position and the players guess
    
    #is the players guess correct?
    if ball_position[guess] == "O":
        print("Correct!")
        print(ball_position)   #show the shuffled list
    else:
        print("Wrong guess!")
        print(ball_position)   #show the shuffled list
```

```
#Putting it all together: order of events

# INITIAL LIST
initial_position = [" ", "O", " "]   #create initial list with preset ball position

#SHUFFLE LIST
shuffled_ball = shuffle_list(initial_position)   #sent initial list to function to be shuffled, returned list assigned to var

#USER GUESS
guess = player_guess()   #call player_guess function to get the players guess of ball position

#CHECK GUESS
check_guess(shuffled_ball,guess)    #pass the shuffled list and the player guess to function check_guess
```

The issues I'm having is that whilst it all seems to work in isolation (the function that shuffles an input list works etc) it doesn't work all together.

(1) No matter what happens the returned shuffled list is ALWAYS shown as ["O", "", ""] i.e. the ball is always in the first position, even though I know it isn't, as if I output the shuffled list manually (in it's own cell) the list is changes most iterations (as it should do).

For instance if I just run these parts of the code:

```
# INITIAL LIST
initial_position = [" ", "O", " "]   #create initial list with preset ball position

#SHUFFLE LIST
shuffled_ball = shuffle_list(initial_position)   #sent initial list to function to be shuffled, returned list assigned to var

shuffled_ball
```

I get a list that changes during most iterations, so I know it's working, but it doesn't seem to work during the main program.

(2) If the player guesses correctly, the check_guess function is supposed to show the list ball_position, but it only does this if the player guess incorrectly, despite there been an explicit print(ball_position) in BOTH parts of the IF ELSE statement. So I have print(ball_position) for a correct guess which never prints the list, and a print(ball_position) in the incorrect guess section, which always works (prints the list if the player guesses wrong. So I don't see how two instructions that are the same can act differently?

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the variable names, or how I've used these in the functions (python functions operate a bit differently to the VB code I'm used to, so maybe I'm missing something?)

Answer (score 0):

Python is tricky with its indentation - it looks like, at least from the code you pasted here, that the logic in your `player-guess()`-function isn't indented properly. When I paste your code into an editor and format it, it works just as you intend it to. Both the shuffling, and the printing of ball position works fine.

Can you double check your indentations in the code?

If this is not the case, do you set a seed somewhere in the code? For example `random.seed(1)`. If you do, this will make it so your shuffles are *always the same* which would result in the bug you're experiencing.

---

EDIT: As a side note, it is redundant to repeat the same code in the two if expressions, i.e:

```py
if ball_position[guess] == "O":
    print("Correct!")
    print(ball_position)   #show the shuffled list
else:
    print("Wrong guess!")
    print(ball_position)   #show the shuffled list
```

Instead, you should put the print afterwards, like so:

```py
if ball_position[guess] == "O":
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong guess!")
print(ball_position)   #show the shuffled list
```

Comment: Hi Emil thanks v. much for the reply. The code actually looks correct re: the indentation, I just copied/pasted it wrong here. I've corrected it so it looks the same here as it does in my Jupyter Notebook. So if it works properly for yourself I'm now very confused as to why it's not working for me!

Good point about the redundant code....I just realised this as I was checking the code again, it doesn't need to be repeated. I still don't understand why it doesn't work though

Comment: I changed the code to this:

`
def check_guess(ball_position,guess):   #create function that takes 2 inputs: ball_position and the players guess
    
    #is the players guess correct?
    if ball_position[guess] == "O":
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong guess!")
        
    print(ball_position)   #show the shuffled list
`

Even though the print(ball_position) is outside the if-else statements, it still doesn't print the list if the player guesses correctly, only if they guess incorrectly

Comment: Apologies for the messy comment, I don't know how to add code tags to the comments section. ``` appears not to work here...

Comment: @TheRobster This sounds strange, and not like a problem with the python logic per se. If you added the `print(ball_position)` to run regardless of the outcome on the `if` statement, then it doesn't matter if the guess is correct or not. And as I said, it all works as intended in my editor. My guess is that something is up with the Jupyter notebook, but it's difficult to say what. You should try the code in an editor, and if that works then try debugging what is up with Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I've figured it out! Because I'm using Juypter Notebooks, even when I'm creating / editing functions I obviously still have to select the cell with the code in and press "Shift+Enter" to make any changes take effect. I didn't realise that this would be needed for functions that you are going to be calling. Obviously Jupyter remembers the previous version regardless of what the current version is if you don't press Shift+Enter in the cell first! Thanks for the replies though, that's been a big help :)